# foreach var x in ... with one result ASP.NET MVC RAZOR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this code:

```
foreach (var parent in @CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf().OrderBy("Level").Skip(2).Take(1))
{
...
}
```

The `@CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf().OrderBy("Level").Skip(2).Take(1)` returns always one result, which is right. In this there is no sense to use foreach loop when the result is only one.

How can i store the result from `@CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf().OrderBy("Level").Skip(2).Take(1)` inside a variable?

Comment: `var parent = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf().....Skip(2).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Btw, i am the command is an umbraco command.

Answer (score 5):

You can call `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` to get the actual object:

```
var value = @CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf().OrderBy("Level").Skip(2).First();
```

The difference between them is that `First()` will throw an exception if there are no items, while `FirstOrDefault()` will return `default(T)` (that is, `null` for reference types and e.g. `0` for `int`s etc).

Since you're extracting the first item, you don't need `Take(1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, i spent 2 hours trying to fix it. I am new in MVC.

Comment: @RuslanDascal: If it solved your problem, do click the little check mark below the vote count on this answer. That helps others looking for the same thing know that this is the solution :)